# Django REST API hangs when ran as a Docker image

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework

Everything works fine when not ran as a Docker image.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5.3-slim
RUN mkdir /django-rest-api
WORKDIR  /django-rest-api
ADD . /django-rest-api
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "./djangorest/manage.py", "runserver"]
```

Build command:

```
docker build -t django-rest-api .
```

Run command:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 django-rest-api
```

manage.py:

```
import os
import sys



print('lol') # <------- the only change from the original file



if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangorest.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

And when I run, it only prints 'lol' when I press ctrl-c:

```
^Clol
```

What makes it wait for an interrupt?

Comment: Does it do the same if you add `-ti` to the run command? (`docker run -ti ...`)

Comment: @DanLowe Thanks ! But I don't get why, even though I read about -i and -t

Comment: If you don't wire up the terminal to your session using `-ti` then it is not in interactive mode, and it buffers output. In that situation it will only dump the buffer to stdout (your terminal) when the buffer reaches 4kb. That's standard Linux i/o behavior. But when you ^C (SIGINT) you forced the buffer dump (and also killed the container, probably).

Comment: @DanLowe I see, thx a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this container, I expect something like the following to be generated on standard output:

```
lol
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 14, 2017 - 22:14:35
Django version 1.10.2, using settings 'djangorest.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

This is in the neighborhood of 250 bytes in length.

Or perhaps if your server is not writing debugging output, it would only be `lol\n`, which is 4 bytes.

You did not use `-ti` in your `docker run` command, so the container has no terminal attached, and is not set to run in interactive mode. In this situation, Docker will use *buffered* output. The standard Linux behavior in this case is to wait until the buffer has accumulated 4096 bytes (4KB) before flushing the buffer to standard output.

However, since you have only output 250 (or maybe only 4) bytes so far, the buffer is still pending. So nothing is written to output for you to see. If you made some requests to the server on port 8000, you would probably shortly reach 4096 bytes and cause a write to output.

This all gets short-circuited when you send SIGINT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>), because the process ends, so the buffer closes and writes to output.